# Plot labels from all sides in confusion matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, confusion-matrix

I need to plot confusion matrix which is annotated from all sides. I have problem with right side where I want to print same labels like in bottom side ([...classes names..., 'Total samples', 'Accuracy' 'mIoU']). Also it seem's that top side ticks are not aligned with bottom side ticks.

Here is what I tried:

```
    fig, ax1 = get_new_fig('Conf matrix default', figsize)

    
    ax = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=annot, annot_kws={"size": fz}, linewidths=lw, ax=ax1,
                    cbar=cbar, cmap=cmap, linecolor='w', fmt=fmt)

    ax_new = ax.twinx().twiny()

    labels = ['' for _ in range(len(ax.get_xticklabels()))]

    labels[-3] = 'Total samples'
    labels[-2] = 'Accuracy'
    labels[-1] = 'mIoU'

    ticks = [tick for tick in ax.get_xticks()]

    ax_new.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax_new.set_yticks(ticks)
    ax_new.yaxis.set_label_position('right')

    ax_new.set_xticklabels([text.get_text() for text in ax.get_xticklabels()], fontsize=10, rotation=-45)  # top
    ax_new.set_yticklabels(labels, fontsize=10, rotation=-25)  # right

    # set ticklabels
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45, fontsize=10)  # bottom
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=25, fontsize=10)  # left
```

[image]

I would really appreciate any help because I have no clue if I am missing something in code or what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the limits of the new `ax`. These need to be equal to the limits of the original `ax`. Especially the fact that the y-axis of the original `ax` is reversed, causes the new y-axis to be without visible tick labels. The different limits also prevent the alignment of the x-axis ticks.

`ax_new.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())` and `ax_new.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())` should solve the problem. `plt.tight_layout()` can help to position all labels nicely in the surrounding plot.

The problem of the rotation of the right y tick labels seems a bit harder. The code below solves it by separating the `twinx` and the `twiny` axes:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Conf matrix default')

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9, 9), columns=range(1, 10), index=range(1, 10))
ax = sns.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 12}, linewidths=2, ax=ax1,
                 cbar=False, linecolor='w', fmt='.2f')

ax_new1 = ax.twinx()
ax_new2 = ax_new1.twiny()

labels = ['' for _ in range(len(ax.get_xticklabels()))]

labels[-3] = 'Total samples'
labels[-2] = 'Accuracy'
labels[-1] = 'mIoU'

ticks = [tick for tick in ax.get_xticks()]

ax_new2.set_xticks(ticks)
ax_new1.set_yticks(ticks)
ax_new1.yaxis.set_label_position('right')

ax_new2.set_xticklabels([text.get_text() for text in ax.get_xticklabels()], fontsize=10, rotation=-45)  # top
ax_new1.set_yticklabels(labels, fontsize=10, rotation=-45)  # right

# set ticklabels
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45, fontsize=10)  # bottom
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=25, fontsize=10)  # left

ax_new2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
ax_new1.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting heatmap]

Comment: Yep exactly, I solved it myself few minutes ago, but now I cannot set rotation lets say 45 ° on right side labels.It seem's to be present on your example as well. I cannot figure out why it does not work.

Comment: `twinx` and `twiny` are a bit tricky. They are still kind of a hack. Each creates a new subplot on the same spot as the previous. Combining `twinx` and `twiny` can result in some conflict.  An alternative could be to just put texts everywhere (using `ax1.text(... , transform=ax1.get_xaxis_transform())`).